# issues with building models using SVC

Tags: svm

I am trying to build an SVM model on Google Colab but it's slow running. I have tried other Models and it worked but only SVM kept executing for the past 4 hours without result.
I have used this code:
`svm_model = SVC(kernel='linear', C=1.0, random_state=42)`

but when it gets to this stage (it becomes slow)- `svm_model.fit(x_train, y_train)`

I tried running SVC on Google Colab to build Models, but it kept running for the past 24 hours. `svm_model = SVC(kernel='linear', C=1.0, random_state=42)`